# Do I need to set the "Explicitly Shared" option?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

For a Facebook, Open Graph action type, what's the meaning of the "Explicitly Shared" property? How does it effect the story? 
If there's a button in my app that publishes a story, does the action need to be "Explicitly Shared" or not?

Any clarifications are welcome,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using Open Graph actions and explicit sharing is more powerful.
Is no need waiting to see FB dialog or confirm your action.

Stories should only be shared explicitly when people indicate that they want to share their in-app experience in the same way that they would post to Facebook themselves. Explicitly shared stories will always be posted to the Timeline of the person who shares them, and might appear in their friends' News Feeds.

Explicit sharing can happen through a variety of actions, like posting a photo or adding a message to an action they've taken. The important thing is that people clearly understand they are posting this action and must opt in to publishing this action to Facebook.

[Learn more](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom)